# KingswaySoft Upsert Bad Request

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

I am currently using KingswaySoft for ETL into Dynamics. We have a need for the upsert action for future trickle loading. Each time I use upsert on a entity (table in dynamics), that has data in it already, I am facing a bad request error.

[Dynamics CRM Destination [2]] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException: CRM service call returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (Error Type / Reason: BadRequest, Detailed Message: --batchresponse_a42eef80-4222-496c-8c69-ff6660222ef4
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
REQ_ID: a9868fb9-d02b-4595-a329-a855c92ced17
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
OData-Version: 4.0

{"error":{"code":"0x80040265","message":"Unhandled Plugin Exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}}
--batchresponse_a42eef80-4222-496c-8c69-ff6660222ef4--
) (SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, v21.1.0.1671 - DtsDebugHost, v15.0.2000.152)KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.WebAPI.WebApiServiceException

: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (Error Type / Reason: BadRequest, Detailed Message: --batchresponse_a42eef80-4222-496c-8c69-ff6660222ef4
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
REQ_ID: a9868fb9-d02b-4595-a329-a855c92ced17
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
OData-Version: 4.0

{"error":{"code":"0x80040265","message":"Unhandled Plugin Exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}}
--batchresponse_a42eef80-4222-496c-8c69-ff6660222ef4--
)System.Net.WebException

(Status Reason: BadRequest): The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.".

I am manually specifying Record Matching Criteria on a primary key from the staging tables that does live on the records in Dynamics.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have received indicates that you have an unhandled null reference error in your custom code, you need to fix the error in your plugin code. Alternatively, you could turn on the "Tentatively Disable Relevant Plugins" option in the CDS/CRM destination component, in which case our software will tentatively disable your plugin while loading the data. In doing so, we do recommend you upgrade your software installation to the latest **v21.2** release that we just made available last week. In the new release, there is the "**Bypass Custom Business Logic**" option which serves the purpose better by bypassing (not actually turning off or disabling) your custom plugins. We hope this helps, please give it a try and share the update with us if you need further assistance.

Comment: I am waiting on our IT department to give us admin access in order to update to version v21.2. In the meantime I had tried the method of using "Tentatively Disable Relevant Plugins" option and I am still receiving the same error. Any other options to try before I get the version updated? Thank you for being quick to respond!

Comment: ^^ To add to this Upsert is working for a different entity. The difference between the packages is that working upsert only has source and destination. The package that isn't working has sorts and merge joins. Hope that adds some context.

Comment: Like we have suggested, please try out the "Bypass Custom Business Logic" option available in the v21.2 release. Again, this is an error from your custom code, it is better to have the issue fixed in the custom code. Our software is just a client software that reports the error situation that thas occurred on the server-side.